# How to use Link Header of HTTP reponse to fetch next batch of data from github API?

Tags: javascript, http-headers, github-api

I'm trying to fetch all Github public repositories with this `GET` request: `https://api.github.com/repositories`

This seems to returns the first `100` repositories. The documentation says,

```
It's important to form calls with Link header values instead of constructing your own URLs.
```

https://developer.github.com/v3/#link-header

My questions is:

1. How should I use the Link header of the `http-response` in Javascript `fetch` Api to get the next batch of data

The above Api seems to return the first 100 APIs and the `link` in the `Response Headers`for the same is something like this:
 `link: <https://api.github.com/repositories?since=369>; rel="next", <https://api.github.com/repositories{?since}>; rel="first"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has this worked out for you? https://github.com/davidcelis/api-pagination/issues/92#issuecomment-360289942

You can access it via: [Response.headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/headers)

`response.headers.get('Link')`

Comment: Yeah I can get access to the Link through `response.headers.get('Link')`. However, my question is how should I make use of this? Do I have to parse the result or something?

Comment: you will need to pull out the link from the header and make a subsequent fetch request for the next "batch" of data

Comment: I get that. But, `link: <https://api.github.com/repositories?since=369>; rel="next", <https://api.github.com/repositories{?since}>; rel="first"` to make use of this result, Do I have to parse this string or is there any other standard way?

Comment: Looks like there is a parser for these link headers here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse-link-header - I couldn't find one that github has released themselves but this should do the trick. Otherwise a bit of regex should work