# Link Headers Missing When Trying To Paginate Products

Tags: node.js, pagination, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

I am trying to paginate products on my shopify app. I followed this tutorial : https://shopify.dev/api/usage/pagination-rest#make-a-paginated-request-and-iterate-through-the-pages. The problem is when i request to the Shopify API, I don't get the Link in the response header.

Here is my code :

```
let url = `https://${req.user.shop}/admin/api/2022-04/products.json?limit=${limit}`;  
 
let options = {
            method: 'GET',
            mode: 'no-cors',
            uri: url,
            json: true,
            headers: {
                'X-Shopify-Access-Token': req.accessToken,
                'content-type': 'application/json',
            }   
        };
 
request(options)
        .then(function (parsedBody){
            console.log(res._headers);
            console.log(parsedBody.products);
            res.status(200).json(parsedBody.products);
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.json(err);
        })
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

```
const response = await fetch(`https://${session.shop}${endpoint}`, requestOptions);
   
if (response.ok) {
  const data = response;
  console.log(response.headers.get('Link')); 
  res.status(response.status).send(data);
} else { 
  console.log(response); 
  res.status(response.status).send(data);
}
```

Comment: yoy have to use response.headers.get('Link')

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61718345/how-to-use-link-header-of-http-reponse-to-fetch-next-batch-of-data-from-github-a

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.